# How to store multiple field values across different pages in a single session object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to store multiple field values across different pages in a single session object and fire that to save all field values in database on button click at the last page. A small snippet of code would help.

Comment: does either of the following replies solve your issue? If yes, please mark it as an Answer so that your question does not remain in the Unanswered questions category. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save all those field values in a class and store that class object directly in session.

Comment: i think the same too. Thanks for the reply. I was wondering how to do that. A snippet of code will help.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is a bit vague but I will respond as per my understanding. This is what you have to do to store values in the `Session` object:

```
    'a string on an aspx page
    Me.Session("Value1") = "My String"
    'an integer on some other aspx page
    Me.Session("Value2") = 100
    'a different string of yet another different aspx page
    Me.Session("Value3") = "Another String"
```

Then on the page where you have button click, you can get these values like this:

```
Dim str1 As String = Convert.ToString(Me.Session("Value1"))
Dim myInt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Me.Session("Value1"))
Dim str2 As String = Convert.ToString(Me.Session("Value3"))
```

Note that I have used different variables to store these values. This is just to give you an idea of how things work but it will be a good approach to have a custom object of yours instead of using many different objects.